# OpenGL - drawing indices from OBJ using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es

I was trying to create an OBJ parser which will read OBJ files and render it using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP. I know OBJ files behaves as TRIANGLES that's why as I read the faces, I rearrange them into STRIPS.

Example I have faces like this

```
    f 5 1 4
    f 5 4 8
    f 3 7 8
```

it will be in this order after I rearrange them minus 1 because OBJ files are 1 based indexes.

```
    f 4 0 3
    f 3 0 4
    f 0 4 3
    f 3 4 7
    f 4 7 2
    f 2 7 6
    f 7 6 7
```

I send this indices to OpenGL and draw them using glDrawElements but the output I get is wrong. Take a look [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBeUs.jpg) for the image.

I based the arrangement on the OpenGL documentation on using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP and I'm stuck on this step as using GL_TRIANGLES works for me. What would cause the incorrect output?

Answer (score 1):

The *.obj* file contains indexes suitable for rendering in **GL_TRIANGLES** mode. You render them in **GL_TRIANGLES_STRIP** mode. You are completely wrong here. Render them in **GL_TRIANGLES** mode and be happy.

Rendering the same index data in other mode is almost always incorrect. **GL_TRIANGLES** mode uses three indices per triangle, while **GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP** uses one index per triangle on average (it is compressed format). So unless you have compressed your index data in approximately three times, you cannot use your indices to draw as **GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP**.

See [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_strip) for details. Below you can see result of rendering indices *{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}* in **GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP**. Obviously, if you render them in **GL_TRIANGLES** mode, you'll see only 2 triangles instead of 5.

[image: GL_TRIANGLES_STRIP example]

Comment: What do you mean by compressed index data? Should I remove the duplicate indices? Im a bit confused now. Sorry :)

Comment: @zyner Drawing *K* indices in **GL_TRIANGLES** mode produces *[K/3]* triangles. Drawing *K* indices in **GL_TRIANGLES_STRIP** mode produces *K-2* triangles. You see: much more triangles drawn for same number of indices. So index data for *T* triangles takes *T+2* elements instead of *3T*, that's what I call compression.

Comment: I get it now. Using same indices will lead to different output because of the behaviour of the 2 primitives on how are they being drawn. But still, I wanna learn how can I draw a model using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP out of an OBJ file? Does the triangulate option when I export it in blender matters?

Comment: @zyner Converting triangles indices to triangle_strip indices is a topic of scientific research. See papers [<1>](https://www.cs.umd.edu/gvil/papers/av_ts.pdf) and [<2>](http://www.cs.umd.edu/gvil/papers/CADstrips.pdf).

Comment: I have read about it and its just too complex for me. Haha is there no other simple way to draw OBJ files as GL_TRIANGLE_STRIPS?

Comment: @zyner No simple way, that's for sure.

Comment: So this will be really bloody coding. Haha but I wanna try the compressed index data but I don't know how to start. I follow the article but I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: @zyneragetro you can convert your mesh to set of multiple triangle strips. You need to group connected triangles to separate strips. You can not use single strip for entire object. The grouping is not simple but can be done prior to rendering by picking up unused triangles from a list and when no other connection found start new strip ... until no triangle is left. The different normal per same vertex must be handled before this by duplicating vertexes ... to preserve sharp edges